# Как можно проверить корректность значения double?

Tags: java, математика, double

Я получаю значение с сервера, но при проверки вылезает ошибка

```
if (results == null) {
 results = 0;
}
```

Comment: result == 0.0??

Comment: Напишите какая ошибка вылезает, а то не понятно в чем проблема.

Comment: double не может быть равен null, но Double может

Answer (score 2):

Как верно написали в комментариях `double` не может быть равен `null`, а `Double` может быть равен `null`, однако это не отменяет того факта, что `double` может не иметь корректного значения.

Посему следовало бы поступить так:

```
if (Double.isNaN(results) || Double.isInfinite(results)) {
    results = 0;
}
```

[NaN - Not a Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) - специальное значение `double`, когда значение не имеет смысла (грубо аналог `null`)

*Infinite* - одно из двух `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITE` или `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITE` - положительное/отрицательная бесконечность.